# Can I define a ISQL or I4GL form wider than 80 columns?

Tags: informix

The docos say "screen size 80 by 20" but I would like to go to 132 columns wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can if the termcap or terminfo entry supports it.  You 'simply' specify the size on the SCREEN line in the form.

In principle, I4GL should detect the screen size automatically, and work happily.  However, there's a chance that you might need to do more than you really should - setting COLUMNS and ROWS as environment variables, for example.  And don't rely on I4GL detecting changes in window size reliably (SIGWINCH).

Comment: You mean like a co#132 in one of the termcap entries?.. I finally got the SE 4.10 engine to work on DOS 6.22. I had to tweak HIMEM.SYS by telling it to use interrupt 15h in order to allocate extended memory, but BCHECK doesn't work, SYSCONSTR.DAT/IDX is corrupted and I cant fix it. I wish I had good manuals for this version.